# My If statement wont work

Tags: sql, sql-server

Im trying to use a sql if statement based on a current record in my database, the code goes:

```
if((Select distinct STUDENT_ID, FLAG, YEAR From EF_STUDENTFLAGS Where STUDENT_ID = '100143795' and YEAR = '16/17').ROW_NUMBER <1)

INSERT INTO EF_STUDENTFLAGS (STUDENT_ID, FLAG, YEAR, COMMENTS, LOGGED_BY, SUBDATE, START_DATE, END_DATE) VALUES ('100143795','Safeguarding','16/17','Test','rhewitson','2014-09-03','2017-02-01','2017-02-01')

else

Update EF_STUDENTFLAGS Set COMMENTS = 'Test', LOGGED_BY = 'rhewitson', SUBDATE = '2014-09-03', START_DATE = '2017-02-01', END_DATE = '2017-02-01' Where STUDENT_ID = '100143795' and YEAR = '16/17'
```

The error message i get is:

> Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

what am i doing wrong??

EDIT:

If there isnt already a record in my database with the same Student id, flag and year as the one i am entering, i want it to create one and if it does exist i want it to update the current record to reflect the most recent version

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That code is product specific.)

Comment: Sql server management studio i believe

Comment: i dont understand what the message is saying... else i would, sql isnt exactly my forte

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Can you please explain a bit more in the question

Comment: At first glance, I would guess that the error seems to come from the UPDATE statement. Your WHERE clause there states: `Where STUDENT_ID = '' and YEAR = '16/17'`. This probably returns multiple students. Try and explicitly change it to use the StudentID you are using in the earlier lines of code.

It's hard to troubleshoot without having more insight into your database and data.

Comment: Sorry, i got that bit wrong, the student id is the same in my actual code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
if Not Exists(Select top 1 1 From EF_STUDENTFLAGS Where STUDENT_ID = '100143795' and YEAR = '16/17')
    INSERT INTO EF_STUDENTFLAGS (STUDENT_ID, FLAG, YEAR, COMMENTS, LOGGED_BY, SUBDATE, START_DATE, END_DATE) VALUES ('100143795','Safeguarding','16/17','Test','rhewitson','2014-09-03','2017-02-01','2017-02-01')
else
    UPDATE EF_STUDENTFLAGS Set COMMENTS = 'Test', LOGGED_BY = 'rhewitson', SUBDATE = '2014-09-03', START_DATE = '2017-02-01', END_DATE = '2017-02-01' Where STUDENT_ID = '100143795' and YEAR = '16/17'
```

Comment: Works, thanks! gotta wait 3 minutes to accept it as the answer though